# Problem with ASP.NET MVC 3 solution layout

Tags: visual-studio, architecture, entity-framework-4, projects-and-solutions

Umm. I though that i would put the contexts, mappings in the ProjectName.Data project and repositories, entities, services, etc. in the ProjectName.Domain project.

However im getting a referencing problem. In Data i need to access the domain namespace and in the domain namespace i need to access the data namespace and when i add reference (Data project get reference to domain and i wanted to have domain get a reference on data) it say that it cannot because that would create a circular dependency.

Any helps ? Where each stuff normally belong to ?

Thanks!

Comment: A lot of this depends on how you are using EF4.  Are you using POCOs?

Comment: Yes. I am using POCOs with EF4 Code-First.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok.  The 'standard' layout is usually more like:

ProjectName.Domain - POCOs

ProjectName.Data - contexts & repositories
* Add a reference to ProjectName.Domain

ProjectName.Services - services
* Add references to ProjectName.Domain and ProjectName.Data

Comment: No problem.  Welcome to the world of architecture!  One interesting thing to note is that many architects will say that you should declare a repository interface in ProjectName.Domain.  For example, if you are working with Products, you will declare IProductRepository in ProjectName.Domain, and the actual repository in ProjectName.Data will implement the interface.  This allows you to test the Domain and Services without having a real Repository in place.

Comment: @anon `ProjectName.Domain` is a `Class Library` but what is `ProjectName.Data`?